# Last $2$ digits of $2^{10000}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I assume I should find $n \le 100$ such that 
$$2^{10000}\equiv n\! \pmod {100}$$
I can see that 
$$2^{10000}= \left(2^{2}\right)^{5000}\equiv 0 \! \pmod {4}$$
and since $\phi (25)=20$ and $gcd(2,25)=1$ we also get 
$$2^{10000}=\left(2^{20}\right)^{500}\equiv 1\! \pmod {25}$$

But since i get different remainders i dont know how to proceed

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342127/find-the-last-two-digits-of-33100?rq=1). You obtain $n=76$.

Comment: I looked all over the web and I have seen CRT mentioned everywhere but not sure how to apply it in this situation

Comment: Or since this is such a small case (applying the Chinese Remainder Theorem here is overkill if you only want to find the solution), simply look at numbers that are 1 more than a multiple of 25 (i.e. 1, 26,...), until you find one that is also a multiple of 4.

Comment: Note that the Chinese remainder theorem tells you you have a solution (and gives a guaranteed method for finding it). But knowing there is a solution you can look for a short-cut computation with confidence.

Comment: $\bmod 25\!:\,\ n = 4k \equiv 1\equiv -24\iff k\equiv -6\iff n=4k\equiv -24\equiv 76\pmod{\!100}\ \ $